# Facebook API error code 110

Tags: android, facebook, publish, fbwebdialogs

have publish dialog and when I use it I have error on one my device.

This situation is only on my one phone...

Can You help me?

My code:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {      
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", getResources().getString(R.string.r_name));
    params.putString("caption","www.url.com");
    params.putString("description", "My desc");
    params.putString("link", getResources().getString(R.string.url_www));
    params.putString("picture", "http://ulr.com");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {



            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {    
            }

        })
        .build();

    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Please Help me with this error.